# что такое потоки STDIN, STDOUT?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь понять многопоточность в PHP.
На одном сайте написано:
Итак, начнем. Для начала закроем потоки STDIN, STDOUT:

```
fclose(STDIN);
fclose(STDOUT);
fclose(STDOERR);
```

Вопрос что это такое и зачем его нужно вначале закрывать? И если запускаю скрипт на локальной машине (денвер), то на эти строки ругается.

Comment: `stdin` (стандартный поток ввода), `stdout` (стандартный поток вывода) и `stderr` (стандартный поток ошибок). Обычно эти потоки направляются к консоли, но в средах, которые поддерживают перенаправление ввода/вывода, они могут быть перенаправлены операционной системой на другое устройство.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

STDIN, STDOUT и STDERR - это три специальных файла, которые связываются с терминалом (на Windows - с консолью) в консольных приложениях.

Файл STDIN (стандартный ввод) по умолчанию "связан" с клавиатурой - все что вы печатаете на клавиатуре, попадает туда.

Файл STDOUT (стандартный вывод) по умолчанию "связан" с монитором - все, что вы запишите в него, вы увидите на экране.

Файл STDERR (стандартный вывод ошибок) - это копия STDOUT. Используется для вывода сообщений об ошибках. Такое разделение сделано для того чтобы можно было перенаправлять их по-отдельности. Так, пайпы (конвейеры) командной строки не трогают STDERR - поэтому нормальный вывод идет дальше по конвейеру, а ошибки отображаются сразу на экране.

Слово "связан" выше я брал в кавычки, потому что никакой прямой связи на самом деле нет. Формально, все три файла по умолчанию связаны с одним и тем же терминалом, а уже терминал как-то обрабатывает нажатия клавиш клавиатуры и выводит надписи на экран.

Закрытие этих файлов в ОС Linux является частью так называемой процедуры демонизации (ухода в фоновой режим), это делается для того чтобы процесс перестал считаться ОС как запущенный на этом терминале.

В многопоточных программах эти файлы часто закрываются для того, чтобы "на их месте" открыть новые. Иными словами, это такой способ для программы перенаправить потоки ввода-вывода самой себе. Смотрите пример далее - там обязательно с этими файлами должно что-то еще делаться.

---

Теперь почему у вас пример не заработал. Причины две, и обе причины заключаются в слове "Денвер".

Во-первых, как я уже говорил, эти файлы - признак консольного скрипта, а не веб-страницы. Скрипт не надо запускать через Денвер, его надо запускать из консоли:

```
`php путь/к/скрипту.php параметры`
```

Возможно, вам следует поискать главу про запуск php из консоли перед тем как браться за многопоточность.

Во-вторых, большинство трюков с этими файлами специфичны для Unix-подобных ОС. Поэтому вам, скорее всего, придется учиться работать с Linux.

Это можно сделать аж 4 путями:

1. Самый радикальный вариант - просто взять и поставить себе Ubuntu. Ubuntu - это довольно популярный дистрибутив Linux для десктопов. Большинство веб-проектов делаются под Linux (можно сказать, Linux в вебе - ОС "по умолчанию"), поэтому такой радикальный шаг оправдан.
2. Можно поднять виртуалку и поставить на нее Debian. Этот вариант приближен к тому, с чем придется столкнуться при попытке выложить результат работы на VDS. Debian - это наиболее стабильный дистрибутив Linux, хорошо подходит для серверов общего назначения. Особенно для учебных серверов.
3. Можно получить аналог окружения linux, поставив себе cygwin. Хороший способ понять "что такое терминал в линуксе" без установки линукса. Наверное, самый простой вариант - ведь все файлы находятся на одном и том же компьютере.
4. Если у вас стоит Windows 10 x64 - можно попробовать [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/14/howto-ubuntu-on-windows-2/?_ga=1.22221244.661752928.1460635898). Сам я с этим совместный творением Canonical и Microsoft не работал - так что сказать чем этот вариант отличается от варианта с cygwin не могу.

Comment: я установил Ubuntu 14.04 на виртуальную машину Oracle, а как дальше работать с Линукс, что это было максимально приближенно к VPS/VDS?

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра чтобы было максимально приближено - удалите все графические программы и работайте из консоли.

Comment: я щас читаю о том, что в Ubuntu Server 64-bit нет графического интерфейса. Может есть смысл его установить. Типа приблизится к реальности. Что Вы посоветуете? И еще вопрос, а смогу ли я пользоваться браузером без графического интерфейса?

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра зачем вам браузер на сервере?

Comment: ну а как проверить то, что я создал. Я думал, что будет типа как денвер на Виндовсе, написал и сразу же и посмотрел как оно работает.

Comment: или я что-то очень сильно путаю и не понимаю?

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра если у вас сервер на виртуалке - то что вам мешает запустить браузер на основной системе и смотреть с нее?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38499/discussion-between---and-pavel-mayorov).

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное, что направили на путь истинный. Вот я нашел отличную статью, где очень все очень подробно описано, как поднять на виртуальной машине веб-сервер, что бы было как VPS.

Answer (score 4):

Потоки STDIN/OUT/ERR никакого отношения к понятию многопоточности не имеют. Под многопоточностью обычно понимают выполнение нескольких потоков команд одного приложения одновременно на разных процессорах (ядрах).

А STD* потоки - это потоки данных STDIN - стандартный ввод программы (то что приходит при вводе с терминала или от браузера клиента). STDOUT - стандартый вывод - то, куда выводят данные команды echo/print, консоль или сокет отправляющий данные браузеру. STDERR - поток сообщений об ошибках.

А вот зачем их закрывать - это надо посмотреть контекст (на том сайте, где вы это прочитали). Закрытие может потребоваться, например для того что бы отвязать программу от управляющего терминала и она стала фоновым процессом операционной системы (выполняется совместно с fork). Или, раз у вас речь про многопоточные приложения, что бы поток выполнения так же оказался независим от терминала операционной системы и, возможно, что бы потом переоткрыл ввод/вывод для общения с другими потоками или процессами.