# stackdriver severity в GKE

Tags: php, laravel, kubernetes, fluentd

Подскажите можно ли в stackdriver сделать разделение по severity. Сейчас все меседжи из контейнера попадают в stderror и в stackdriver они маркируются как ошибки. Задача разделить сообщения из логов (laravel) по категориям info, error, warning.

Google Kubernetes Engine + Stackdriver logging enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Существуют 2 основных потока вывода
stdout (стандартный поток вывода) и stderr (стандартный поток ошибок)

Вам нужно определить, что в какой поток, какие события вы отправляете

Пример реализации перенаправления основных событий и ошибок можно посмотреть например в [nginx Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/mainline/buster/Dockerfile#L96)
Подробней о потоках можно почитать в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512946/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-stdin-stdout)